# Next js - Next Auth - Keep having error=OAuthCreateAccount (google provider)

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have set up next-auth with the GoogleProvider.

Everything works fine locally, however in production, I am having aOAuthCreateAccount error: api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCreateAccount

stating "Try signing in with a different account."

I have provided the ID & Secret of the Provider, I have dropped my DB, tried to log with multiples accounts... I do not understand. Is there something that my production environment is not accessing?

Here's my nextauth.js:

`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb";


export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),

    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  // Can custom page & path
  pages: {
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
    error: "/auth/error", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // (used for check email message)
    // newUser: "/auth/new-user", // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
    newUser: "/recruiter/2", // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
  },
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
});
```

`

And my mongodb.js:
`

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error("Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local");
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

`

Thank you!

Read the documentations.
Look on Stackoverflow and github thread, tried all the offered solutions, in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it reading this thorough article: https://medium.com/geekculture/why-and-how-to-get-started-with-next-auth-61740558b45b

I was missing the database variable in my deployment system (vercel) :)